# Override Default Language settings in Bot Composer

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

How to override **DefaultLanguage** Settings of bot composer inside any dialog?

By default language settings is "en-US".

Say after showing welcome message in Greeting Dialog, I want to override default language settings from "en-US" to "it-it"(Italian)

**Note:** I am using wats app channel.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-use-multiple-language#how-does-multilingual-support-work

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement a language selector based on the user's choice.

First, multi-language must be implemented as shown in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-use-multiple-language#how-does-multilingual-support-work).

Second, after welcoming the user, I ask him the language he wants to select (this is in my case, you can adapt it according to your conditions). I did this with a multiple selector.
After the user selects the language, some variables are saved with the selected language code. In my case it had en-us and fr-fr.

[image: Language selection and saving of variables]

The variables to save are:

```
user.locale
turn.locale
turn.activity.locale
```

Finally, you have to add a trigger of type Activity received. Details can be seen in the image below.
[image: Activity received]